# Insert New Item from front end with converted SQL Server Backend

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a front end access file where I recently converted the backend to SQL Server 2012.  I followed the best practices and used the Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access.

Most of the application is working flawlessly, however I have the problem that in detailed grid views the empty line (as in to add new row of data) does not appear when it is linked to the SQL backend.  When it is linked to the access back end it appears no problem.

Comment: Does Access recognize a primary key in that linked table?  If not, it will treat the linked table as read-only and not offer you an opportunity to add a new row.  If that is the issue, you could revise the SQL Server table to include a timestamp field and then refresh the Access link so that it is aware of that new field.

Comment: @HansUp So I would would need to recreate the table and move the data to it, correct.  Are there any other caveats with getting it to recognize the primary key ?

Comment: I meant add a SQL Server timestamp field to the existing table.  That does not require creating a new table and loading data into it.  (Timestamp is an available data type in SQL Server.)  Access can use a timestamp field in the linked table, instead of a primary key, to identify records and allow the linked table to be treated as read-write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can not add a new record to a table (or gridview), it means the recordset isn't updateable.  With a SQL Server backend, this usually means one or more of the tables doesn't have a Primary Key.  You can use anything for said key (I usually use an AutoNumber field), but that key must exist in order for SQL Server to be able to add a new record.

See the accepted answer in this question for a similar issue with the same suggested fix:

["operation must use an updateable query" for UPDATE query on SQL linked table in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952437/operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-for-update-query-on-sql-linked-table-in)