# MSAccess - Oracle: Cant add record to form recordset

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc

I have a MSAccess application and I want to migrate data to an Oracle DB. I have tables already linked to the new location and I can navigate through records, but I'm finding some issues. One of them is that I have a form with a "new record" button which is giving a 2105 error “You can't go to the specified record” in the DoCmd line below.

```
Private Sub cmbNew_Click()

  DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec 'Error here
  [...]

End Sub
```

The form datasource is a single table, no complex queries. I'm using a privileged user to access linked tables (it should not be a problem of R/W permissions).

Thanks.

Comment: Form AllowAdditions property set to Yes? Can you add record directly in linked table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/20952437/2144390

Comment: Solved. The oracle tables were a copy from access and the copy process didn't create a pk. I've added it and I've been able to add a new record and update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, forget the form for the time being, and directly open up the linked table. Can you move to a new row/record and add it? No use trying all kinds of forms and code if the linked table don't allow adding of records. And while we are at this, did you try editing a record when you open the linked table? (again, no use trying all kinds of forms code, VBA and all that fancy stuff - always just try opening the table first, and see if you can edit). Then and ONLY then do you want to start messing with forms.

In most cases, the reason(s) why you can't edit (or add) data  in a linked table are:

The linked table does not have a primary key set. When you link a table, after linking, the above 2 second test is a good idea. You can also open the linked table in design view, and take a quick check to see if the linked table "sees" the PK.

So, you want the table on the server side to have a PK. And of course it likely will be some kind of autonumber column in addition to having been set with a PK.

If the linked table does not have a PK (or access can't figure out and see the PK), then the table will be read only - you not be able to edit, and of course not be able to add new rows.

Comment: You're right. I've added a pk and it works. Thank you!